# A function to produce M fragments of DNA with length of I

Tags: r, for-loop

I want a script in R, which creates `M` fragments of DNA with a length of `I` but with **GC content** of >70%

I know this gives something but not exactly what I am looking for

```r
require(Biostrings)

set = NULL
for (i in 1:4)
  set = c(set, paste(sample(DNA_ALPHABET[1:4], 3, replace=T), collapse=""))
rep(set,2)
```

Any idea please?

Comment: Why R though? If the need is to simulate sequences, why do you need to do it R - why not look for the best way to do it using any language/tool?

Comment: Also by this point you should know better than to use `set` as a variable name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different ways to approach the GC bias, the easiest is probably to decide beforehand how many "A/T" and how many "G/C" we need in each sequence, then choose them randomly.

```r
# set global parameters
M <- 7
I <- 15

# for each sequence, choose a proportion of GC
prop_gc <- runif(M,
                 min = .7,
                 max = 1)

# randomly choose bases, ensure we have a number that gives us at least `prop_gc`
bases <- lapply(prop_gc,
                \(.prop_gc){
                  c(
                    sample(c("A","T"),
                           size = floor(I*(1 - .prop_gc)), replace = TRUE),
                    sample(c("G","C"),
                           size = ceiling(I*.prop_gc), replace = TRUE)
                  )
                })

# now we can simply take our bases and combine them (in a random order)
sequences <- sapply(bases,
                    \(.nt) sample(.nt) |> paste(collapse = ""))

sequences
#> [1] "CGGCTTCCGCGCGGGT" "CTACCCACGGCGCCGG" "GGGCGGTGTATGTGCC" "GGCCCGGGTGCCCAGC"
#> [5] "GCGGGCGCGGGCGGGT" "CACCCCCTCCCGGGAC" "GTCGAAGCGCGCCAGC"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Or same thing with a `for` loop (since you gave it as a tag):

```r
M <- 7
I <- 15

sequences <- character(length = M)
for(i in seq_len(M)){
  prop_gc <- runif(1,
                   min = .7,
                   max = 1)
  
  bases <- c(
    sample(c("A","T"),
           size = floor(I * (1 - prop_gc)), replace = TRUE),
    sample(c("G","C"),
           size = ceiling(I * prop_gc), replace = TRUE)
  )
  
  sequences[[i]] <- sample(bases) |> paste(collapse = "")
  
}
sequences
#> [1] "CCCCGGTTGCGTTTCC" "CCTCGCTGCGCGTGGC" "CAGTCTCCCGCGGGGC" "GGGCCCGCCGAAAGGC"
#> [5] "GCGCGGGGCCGGTCAG" "CGGGCGCCCTGGACAC" "ACTCTGCGGGGGAGTC"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

And we can doublecheck the results:

```r
M <- 7000
I <- 500

[...]

# check
gc_prop <- function(x){
  toupper(x) |>
    strsplit("") |>
    sapply(\(.char) mean(.char == "C" | .char == "G"))
}

sapply(sequences, nchar) |> table()
#> 
#>  500 
#> 7000

min(gc_prop(sequences))
#> [1] 0.702
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>